# local variable 'ras_APAR' referenced before assignment ArcPy error

Tags: arcpy, unboundlocalerror

I am trying to multiply different raster from different subfolder. and during calculation of raster trying to give a msak of raster. i have written a code but its giving error. here is my code along with error mrssage

Error Message

```
lst_ras_APAR [u'r001_APAR.TIF', u'r002_APAR.TIF', u'r003_APAR.TIF', u'r004_APAR.TIF', u'r005_APAR.TIF', u'r006_APAR.TIF', u'r007_APAR.TIF', u'r008_APAR.TIF', u'r009_APAR.TIF', u'r010_APAR.TIF', u'r011_APAR.TIF', u'r012_APAR.TIF']
lst_ras_TScalar [u'r001_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r002_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r003_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r004_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r005_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r006_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r007_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r008_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r009_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r010_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r011_TSCALAR.TIF', u'r012_TSCALAR.TIF', u'T_SCALAR_001.tif', u'T_SCALAR_002.tif', u'T_SCALAR_003.tif', u'T_SCALAR_004.tif', u'T_SCALAR_005.tif', u'T_SCALAR_006.tif', u'T_SCALAR_007.tif', u'T_SCALAR_008.tif', u'T_SCALAR_009.tif', u'T_SCALAR_010.tif', u'T_SCALAR_011.tif', u'T_SCALAR_012.tif']
lst_ras_WScalar [u'r001_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r002_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r003_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r004_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r005_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r006_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r007_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r008_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r009_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r010_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r011_WSCALAR.TIF', u'r012_WSCALAR.TIF']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<module2>", line 59, in <module>
 File "<module2>", line 32, in main
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ras_apar' referenced before assignment
```

**

```
def main():
 import arcpy
 import os
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
 # Checkout extension
 arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Workspace Folder
 ws_in_apar = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\APAR'
 ws_in_tscalar = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\TScalar'
 ws_in_wscalar = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\WScalar'
 ws_out_NPP = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\NPP'

# list "apar" rasters (e.g r001_APAR, r002_APAR so on  )
 arcpy.env.workspace = ws_in_apar
 lst_ras_APAR = arcpy.ListRasters()
 print "lst_ras_APAR", lst_ras_APAR

# list "tscalar" rasters (e.g r001_TSCALAR, r002_TSCALAR so on )
 arcpy.env.workspace = ws_in_tscalar
 lst_ras_TScalar = arcpy.ListRasters()
 print "lst_ras_TScalar", lst_ras_TScalar

 # list "wscalar" rasters (e.g r001_WSCALAR, r002_WSCALAR so on)
 arcpy.env.workspace = ws_in_wscalar
 lst_ras_WScalar = arcpy.ListRasters()
 print "lst_ras_WScalar", lst_ras_WScalar

for ras_name in lst_ras_APAR:
 ras_APAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_apar, ras_APAR))
 print "ras_apar", ras_apar

for ras_TSCALAR in lst_ras_TSCALAR:
 ras_TSCALAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_tscalar, ras_TSCALAR))
 print "ras_TSCALAR", ras_TSCALAR

 for ras_WSCALAR in lst_ras_WSCALAR:
 ras_WSCALAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_wscalar, ras_WSCALAR))
 print "ras_WSCALAR", ras_WSCALAR

# calculate 
 ras_NPP = (ras_APAR * ras_TSCALAR * ras_WSCALAR * 0.98)

#Process rectricted within mask file : Process will occur only on location that fall within the mask
 #else it will be assigned to nodata inthe output
 mask="D:\MOD-REF\NDVI\CROP-L-OCT-15.img"
 NPP_Mask = ExtractByMask(ras_NPP, mask)

 # save raster
 ras_num = ras_name[:3]
 out_name_NPP = os.path.join(ws_out_NPP, 'r{0}_NPP.TIF'.format(ras_num))
 NPP_Mask.save(out_name_NPP)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Updated Code below , Error still existing.

```
def main():

        import arcpy
        import os
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        # Checkout extension
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

        # avoid using - in folders in combination with raster calculations!
        ws_in_apar = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\APAR'
        ws_in_tscalar = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\TScalar'
        ws_in_wscalar = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\WScalar'
        ws_out_NPP = r'D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\NPP'

        # list "apar" rasters (e.g r001_APAR)
        arcpy.env.workspace = ws_in_apar
        lst_ras_APAR = arcpy.ListRasters()
        print "lst_ras_APAR", lst_ras_APAR

        # list "tscalar" rasters (e.g r012_TSCALAR)
        arcpy.env.workspace = ws_in_tscalar
        lst_ras_TScalar = arcpy.ListRasters()
        print "lst_ras_TScalar", lst_ras_TScalar


        # list "wscalar" rasters (e.g r001_WSCALAR)
        arcpy.env.workspace = ws_in_wscalar
        lst_ras_WScalar = arcpy.ListRasters()
        print "lst_ras_WScalar", lst_ras_WScalar

        for ras_name in lst_ras_APAR:
            ras_APAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_apar, ras_APAR))
            print "ras_APAR", ras_APAR

        for ras_TSCALAR in lst_ras_TSCALAR:
            ras_TSCALAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_tscalar, ras_TSCALAR))
            print "ras_TSCALAR", ras_TSCALAR


        for ras_WSCALAR in lst_ras_WSCALAR:
            ras_WSCALAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_wscalar, ras_WSCALAR))
            print "ras_WSCALAR", ras_WSCALAR

            # calculate 
            ras_NPP = (ras_APAR * ras_TSCALAR * ras_WSCALAR * 0.98)

       #Process rectricted within mask file : Process will occur only on location that fall within the mask
       #else it will be assigned to nodata inthe output
            mask="D:\MOD-REF\NDVI\CROP-L-OCT-15.img"
            NPP_Mask = ExtractByMask(ras_NPP, mask)


            # save raster
            ras_num = ras_name[:3]
            out_name_NPP = os.path.join(ws_out_NPP, 'r{0}_NPP.TIF'.format(ras_num))
            NPP_Mask.save(out_name_NPP)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive for everything but paths. `ras_APAR` is not the same as `ras_apar`. Change `ras_apar` (this variable hasn't been instantiated) to its upper-case version and it will work.

Comment: I have changed it it to ras_apar, but still same error

Comment: i replaced the line given you you. But still facing same error

Comment: You should replace `ras_apar` with `ras_APAR`, not the opposite.. Could you please update your code?

Comment: I have updated. Please look at the code.

Comment: You probably mean `ras_APAR = arcpy.Raster(os.path.join(ws_in_apar, ras_name))`. Could you please show the updated error too?

Comment: There is another occurence of `ras_name` under the last block which doesn't make sense: `# save raster
        ras_num = ras_name[:3]`

Comment: I have changed the code suggested by you, now i getting the follwing error `Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> <module2> 58  
    main <module2> 36  
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset D:\MODIS-NDVI-2012\TScalar\r012_APAR.TIF does not exist or is not supported`

Comment: Tscalar taking wrong path

Comment: Please can you tell after updated, why the another error occurring

Comment: Sorry but I'm lost. I don't even know which line raises the error. I can fix obvious code errors but this site is not meant to provide in-depth code-reviewing. I suggest you to add print statements here and there to check your variables' value an help you locate the error.

Comment: the code is successfully run but my output name is not same as i assigned, Output name is`rr001_WSCALAR.TIF_NPP.TIF`  but it should be like this `001_NPP.TIF`